# Android databinding swallows errors from other compilers

Tags: android, android-databinding

If there are any errors during compilation, the databinding classes arent generated - and as such, I get a ton of errors like this:

```
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class TrainingActivityCompletedSetBinding
  e: S:\ProjectLocation\TrainingActivityCompletedSetBinding.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
  @Nullable DataBindingComponent component)
```

**The problem is that the compilation error isnt related to databinding at all, and as such I have no idea whats actually causing it - and I have to manually dig into the files to find the issue.**

In the example above, I just omitted `@Inject` from a constructor that requires it. Itd be lovely to see the error message from Dagger in this case so that I can find it immediately, rather than having to dig into all the projects classes to find it manually.

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated!

---

Both Android Studio & Databinding is on version 3.1.3 currently, the error has been there since 3.0 at least.

Using Kotlin V1.2.41, and kapt for generating code.

Tried increasing the max number of errors the compiler would show, unfortunately no difference.

Temporarily, a workaround is to simply disable databinding V2: `android.databinding.enableV2=true` in *gradle.properties*. Still open to a better solution though.

Comment: @Luksprog I tried that with no luck; forgot to include it in the post - sorry!

Comment: My LORD!!!! My pleasant for you!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cannot write a comment, so I'll write it here.
Probably you wanted to say to add a line like this: `android.databinding.enableV2=false`, so it'll work right.

Comment: This does not work for me with android studio 3.4.1, com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 and kotlin version 1.2.71. Might be a workaround for Dagger but not others.

Comment: Great Works. This fixed the issue. My environment

tools build gradle 3.2.1@Aqluse

Answer (score 1):

I see that you said that you tried increasing the max number of errors that the compiler would show, but in case it helps others who find their way here:

Instead of disabling V2 databinding, you can follow this forum post which demonstrates how to extend the number of displayed errors.  This fixed my issue without disabling the V2 each time.

This fixed my problem *even though* the number of errors I was shown wasn't a conspicuously round number, so I'm not sure how the counting works.

https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/306

Answer (score 0):

I've quoted and continued the answer from @Aqluse [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51352581/3763032) also from another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50637143/3763032).

Here's the alternative what to solve this data binding issue.

```
1. kapt "androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:${your gradle version}"
2. android.databinding.enableV2=false
3. check your missing or wrong import XML **check your version control**
4. upgrade your android studio to the latest stable
```