# :app:kaptDevDebugKotlin FAILED Build exception: cannot find symbol DataBindingComponent

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin

I've been trying to solve this annoying issue for way too long without any progress.

Our application has most classes written in Kotlin, and we are using databinding as well:

```
apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"  
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'  
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

When trying to run de application, we see multiple exceptions as the following in the build dialog (when I say multiple, I mean more than 50):

```
e: .../android/app/build/generated/source/dataBinding/baseClasses/dev/debug/com/company/app/databinding/IncludeFilterHeaderTabButtonBinding.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
  protected IncludeFilterHeaderTabButtonBinding(DataBindingComponent _bindingComponent, View _root,
                                                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class IncludeFilterHeaderTabButtonBinding
```

This app imports a home made SDK, which is entirely written in Java, and uses data binding as well. Is there any known issue from doing this?

This are the dependencies for the main app:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1'  
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'  
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'  
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'  
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'  
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'  
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'  
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'  

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:12.0.1'  
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'  

implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'  
implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.6.0'  

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'  
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'  
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'  
kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.3"

implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'  
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'  

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'  
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'  
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.3.0'  

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'  
implementation 'org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.+'  

implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9'  

implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'  

// Home made SDK initialization per flavor and build type
implementation(name: 'appauth-1.0.2', ext: 'aar')  
mockDebugCompile(name: 'sdk-mock-debug', ext: 'aar')  
mockReleaseCompile(name: 'sdk-mock-release', ext: 'aar')  
devDebugCompile(name: 'sdk-dev-debug', ext: 'aar')  
devReleaseCompile(name: 'sdk-dev-release', ext: 'aar')  
proDebugCompile(name: 'sdk-pro-debug', ext: 'aar')  
proReleaseCompile(name: 'sdk-pro-release', 'ext': 'aar')  

// Testing
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
// Crashlytics Kit
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

With the following versions:

Android Studio 3.1.3
Gradle 3.1.3
Kotlin Gradle Plugin 1.2.51

Of course, we have

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Adding the output from ./gradlew build --stacktrace

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDevDebugKotlin'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwGradleExceptionIfError(tasksUtils.kt:8)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptTask.compile(KaptTask.kt:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:780)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:747)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        ... 29 more
```

**UPDATE 2**

I've been forced to check every single file in my project, looking for errors not logged by gradle... and after fixing a few Java files, the error has shifted from the original "cannot find symbol" to a single exception:

```
e: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding Unable to get public no-arg constructor
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:672)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.access$1000(ServiceLoader.java:390)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1232)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1264)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1299)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1384)
        at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.toCollection(_Collections.kt:1058)
        at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.toMutableList(_Collections.kt:1091)
        at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.toList(_Collections.kt:1082)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.loadProcessors(Kapt3Extension.kt:106)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:175)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:93)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:97)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:107)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:84)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:374)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:64)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:101)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:365)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:130)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:161)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:63)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:108)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:52)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:451)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:97)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:218)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:37)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:80)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:92)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:527)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:97)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:408)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:97)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:909)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:97)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:939)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:908)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:407)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3090)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3295)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2110)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:659)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:656)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:667)
        ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
        ... 65 more
```

Fortunately (I guess? IDK any more) after a quick clean and invalidate/restart everything went back to "normal" with the initial multiple exceptions.

So, for now, all I can do is keep checking and fixing until there aren't any errors left, and then we'll see... stay tuned.

Comment: What dependency are you using for `databinding-compiler`?

Comment: Thank you for responding! I've edited the answer with the complete dependency list for our app

Comment: This is probably because of some error in your layout file. Check gradle output with patience, the error message should be somewhere in it, but it is not included in what you pasted here. Should be somewhere not far above the stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I'm afraid there isn't any additional information to be found in gradle output other than the "cannot find symbol DataBindingComponent" multiple times. I'll dig manually into every xml to see if there's any unreported error, but honestly I doubt it.

Comment: Update: no XML file seems to have any errors, or Android Studio isn't showing me where they might be. I've tried using gradlew build --info: it requested creating Kotlin folders for some flavor/buildtype combinations, which obviously did nothing. On the other hand gradlew build --debug outputs a ton of lines, but none of them points to any specific issue. At this point, I'm concerned about the lack of feedback provided by this IDE...

Comment: Possibly related: [Android databinding swallows errors from other compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50755768/90527)

Comment: That's exactly my current issue! Thank you. Fortunately, I've managed to move along, but I'll provide my experience in that question as well :)

Answer (score 7):

**FINALLY!** I managed to make it compile. It was a matter of checking every single piece of code... a very pleasing experience, I will recommend it to all my friends.

As pointed out by outis in the comments of the question (thank you!), [I am not the only one experiencing this funny error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50755768/android-databinding-swallows-errors-from-other-compilers).

I'm creating my own answer as I can continue development. However, I don't think it's good enough. Therefore, I'm not marking it as the accepted answer as the compiler output is broken and unusable, and it will surely haunt my dreams in the future.

**UPDATE**

I've runned into this issue again recently, and I've noticed that, for some reason, declaring a view's id before the actual view (i.e. @+id/someview) doesn't mean that the view itself can use that same id (as @id/someview). AFAIK, this issue is non existant without databinding... so watch out!

Comment: feeling sorry for u man. BTW I found another solution!!1! not using `kapt` (and dependency injection) in my case, until that crap is stable!

Comment: I took a similar approach. Ultimately, it turned out that I had an annotation defined twice (I was porting over some code that had several annotation files that were actually duplicates of ones included by a similar library).

Answer (score 2):

This is brutal,

The way I managed to make it work is install java 8 on the local machine, run `./gradlew` from the local machine.

This way I get the compilation errors fix them and then compile from Android Studio that uses it's own java version and will not fail anymore.

Comment: I upvote this answer as a gesture of solidarity.

Answer (score 2):

***In my case***, I have faced the same issue while I have upgraded "kotlin-gradle-plugin: from 1.5.31 to 1.6.10".

I have solved this issue by Upgrading **Gradle Version** to the latest version by following official docs. https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle

In android studio got to **File>Project Structure>Project>Gradle Version** here select the latest version of Gradel.

***I think***, This happens when we update "kotlin-gradle-plugin" and the other dependencies are not the latest version.

Also, Check your JDK version you can follow official docs.

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#jdk

Answer (score 0):

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#flavor-support

androidExtensions.experimental is support flavor

```
androidExtensions.experimental=true
```