# Kotlin Dagger2 - cannot find symbol DataBindingComponent

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-2

I'm trying to use Dagger2 with Kotlin but getting an untraceable error. I've tried many ways to resolve this problem but all doesn't work. This is my stacktrack by **./gradlew build --stacktrace** command:

```
e: /home/rahul/Documents/AndroidStudioProjects/RetailUser/app/build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug/out/com/retailuser/databinding/ItemFleetListingEmptyViewBinding.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class ItemFleetListingEmptyViewBinding
e: /home/rahul/Documents/AndroidStudioProjects/RetailUser/app/build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug/out/com/retailuser/databinding/ItemFleetListingEmptyViewBinding.java:73: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class ItemFleetListingEmptyViewBinding
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.onHandleStep(ProcessExpressions.java:77)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.runStep(ProcessDataBinding.java:203)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.access$000(ProcessDataBinding.java:188)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.doProcess(ProcessDataBinding.java:90)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.process(ProcessDataBinding.java:65)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:99)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1068)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:55)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:27)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:213)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:178)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:96)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:95)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:105)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:82)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:375)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:67)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:107)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:366)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:120)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:161)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:57)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:96)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:52)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:93)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:441)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1020)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1062)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1019)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:440)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwGradleExceptionIfError(tasksUtils.kt:16)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithKotlincTask.compile(KaptWithKotlincTask.kt:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:788)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:755)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
        ... 30 more
```

**Build.gradle (App)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply from: '../config/quality/quality.gradle'


android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.retailuser"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://www.mocky.io/v2\"")
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://www.mocky.io/v2\"")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // android support libraries
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:$rootProject.constraintLayout"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
//    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4"

    // image
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$rootProject.glideVersion"
    // parser
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$rootProject.gsonVersion"
    // reactive
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rootProject.rxjava2Version"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rootProject.rxandroidVersion"
    // dependencies for local unit tests
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$rootProject.ext.junitVersion"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$rootProject.mockitoVersion"
    testAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    // UI Testing
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$rootProject.espressoVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$rootProject.espressoVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$rootProject.mockitoVersion"
    androidTestAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    // view model
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$rootProject.lifecycle"
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$rootProject.lifecycle"
    // dependency injection
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    //mapbox
    implementation "com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:$rootProject.mapboxVersion"
    //FloatActionButton
    implementation "com.github.clans:fab:$rootProject.fab"
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibraryVersion"
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
}
```

**build.gradle(root)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

// Define versions in a single place
ext {
    // Sdk and tools
    minSdkVersion = 17
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.2'

    // App dependencies
    supportLibraryVersion = '28.0.0'
    constraintLayout = '1.1.3'
    gsonVersion = '2.8.2'
    calligraphyVersion = '2.2.0'
    glideVersion = '3.7.0'
    roomDatabase = '1.0.0'
    rx2FastAndroidNetworking = '1.0.1'

    fab = '1.6.4'
//    fab = '1.0.6'
    mapboxVersion = '6.3.0'
    dagger2Version = '2.14.1'
    rxjava2Version = '2.1.9'
    rxandroidVersion = '2.0.2'
    placeholderviewVersion = '0.6.1'
    debugDBVersion = '1.0.3'
    timberVersion = '4.5.1'
    lifecycle = '1.1.1'

    // Test dependencies
    junitVersion = '4.12'
    espressoVersion = '3.0.1'
    mockitoVersion = '2.15.0'
}
```

**Application class**

```
public class UserApp extends Application implements HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityDispatchingAndroidInjector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .application(this)
                .build()
                .inject(this);

    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return activityDispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
}
```

**Application Component**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AndroidInjectionModule.class, AppModule.class, ActivityBuilder.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    void inject(RetailUserApp app);

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        AppComponent build();
    }
}
```

**Application Module**

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Context provideContext(Application application) {
        return application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    DataManager provideDataManager(AppDataManager appDataManager) {
        return appDataManager;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Gson provideGson() {
        return new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
    }

    @Provides
    @PreferenceInfo
    String providePreferenceName() {
        return AppConstants.PREF_NAME;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    PreferencesHelper providePreferencesHelper(AppPreferencesHelper appPreferencesHelper) {
        return appPreferencesHelper;
    }

    @Provides
    SchedulerProvider provideSchedulerProvider() {
        return new AppSchedulerProvider();
    }
}
```

**ItemFleetListingEmptyViewBinding**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.retailuser.ui.fleetlisting.FleetListingEmptyItemViewModel" />

    </data>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_30"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dimen_7"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/dimen_4"
        app:contentPadding="@dimen/dimen_10">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewEmpty"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_90"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_90"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_5"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_frown_face" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_message"
                style="@style/TextViewStyle"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_15"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/empty_screen"
                android:textColor="@color/gray" />

            <!-- <TextView
                 style="@style/TextViewStyle"
                 android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_30"
                 android:text="@string/please_retry"
                 android:textColor="@color/gray" />-->

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_retry"
                style="@style/ButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_120"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_15"
                android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onRetryClick()}"
                android:text="@string/retry"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_18" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</layout>
```

I've already tried to clean and rebuild the project but it didn't work.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you updated `fab = '1.0.6'` to `fab = '1.6.4'`?

Comment: What Android studio version are you using?

Comment: no, I was using it before but most of the classes is in java from last few days I started using kotlin in this project and after compilation, I am getting this weard error

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS  3.2.1

Comment: "I've tried many ways .." maybe share some of that info in the question? Also, the build log may have more details.

Comment: Can you post your `ItemFleetListingEmptyViewBinding` layout?

Comment: edited please check @ConstOrVar

Comment: @Rahul did you check my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line : `kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4"` because it's included with the new version.

Rarely if it doesn't work change `kapt` for `annotationProcessor`

Also you can take a look on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52550118/4385913)

Comment: thank you so much after removing: kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4" i got clear error and the file name that contains error